# Keep form window open when form is submitted

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, fancybox

Consider this image which is an iframe window when user clicks on a link.

[image]

**My Problem**

When user clicks deposit the form gets submitted and ***the window closes***, thus the user does not know if deposit was successful or not.

**What I want to do**

I am looking for a way to **keep the iframe window open** after the form has been submitted, to display appropriate message

**Form HTML**

```
   <form name="depForm" action="" id="register_form" method="post">
            User Name<br /><input type="text" name="uname" value="" /><br />
            Credit Card Nr<br /><input type="text" name="cc" value="" /><br />
            CSV Nr<br /><input type="text" name="csv" value="" /><br />
            Amount<br /> <input type="text" name="amount" value="" /><br />
            <input type="submit" value="deposit" name="deposit" class="buttono" />
            </form>
```

**PHP Code**

```
if(isset($_POST['deposit'])){
            if(isset($_SESSION['FBID'])){
                $uid=$_SESSION['FBID'];
                $amount = $_POST['amount'];
                $cc = $_POST['cc'];
                $csv = $_POST['csv'];
                //new bal
                $bal = getBal($uid);
                $newBal = $bal+$amount;
                $sql="UPDATE members SET balance='$newBal' WHERE member_nr='$uid'";
                $result = mysql_query($sql) or die("error please try again");   
                    if($result){

                    }
            }
```

if anyone can advise me how to keep iframe open after form has been submitted it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You would need to change the form submission to use AJAX. In the response you can include a state flag to indicate to the UI whether the request was successful or not and act appropriately.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yeah I thought it would need to use AJAX (sigh) dont know much about Ajax,,,guess it is back to the tutorials for me

Comment: I added an answer for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to change the form submission to use AJAX. In the response you can include a state flag to indicate to the UI whether the request was successful or not and act appropriately. Something like this:

```
$('#register_form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the standard form submission
    $.ajax({
        url: this.action,
        type: this.method,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.success) {
                // show success message in UI and/or hide modal
            } else {
                // it didn't work
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            // something went wrong with the server. diagnose with the above properties
        }
    });
});
```

```php
$success = false;
if (isset($_POST['deposit'])) {
    if (isset($_SESSION['FBID'])) {
        $uid = $_SESSION['FBID'];
        $amount = $_POST['amount'];
        $cc = $_POST['cc'];
        $csv = $_POST['csv'];

        $bal = getBal($uid);
        $newBal = $bal + $amount;
        $sql = "UPDATE members SET balance='$newBal' WHERE member_nr='$uid'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die("error please try again");   
        if ($result) {
            $success = true;
        }
    }
}

echo json_encode(array('success' => $success));
```

Comment: Thank you so much, for your effort, wish I could do more than simply giving you an upvote, I really appreciate this

Comment: Im embarrassed to ask you such a stupid question but my Ajax knowledge is non existent....where should I insert the 1st part of the code...the ajax part?

Comment: In a jQuery document ready handler. If you're unfamiliar with jQuery, [here's a guide](https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/)

Comment: Thanks Rory, you are great!